# Convert SQLServer sql to Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a SQL to view table master and detail. How convert to linq. Please help me :

```
Select B.idchatuser,B.Nama, B.Hp,
(select TOP 1 CreatedTime from ChatUserConversation 
where IdChatUser = B.IdChatUser order by CreatedTime) CreatedTime
from ChatUser B 
order by CreatedTime desc
```

Comment: Have you tried Linqer http://www.sqltolinq.com ?

Comment: Please make an attempt, Arly. We are not a code-writing service. The query is relatively simple, you should be able to make a start.

Comment: @Kason : Thanks for the solution, i have downloaded and tried Linqer. But I do not understand how to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
from B in ChatUser
join C in ChatUserConversation on B.IdChatUser equals C.IdChatUser
group new {B,C} by new {B.IdChatUser, B.Nama, B.Hp} into g
let CreatedTime = g.OrderBy(x=>x.C.CreatedTime).Select(x=>x.C.CreatedTime).FirstOrDefault()
orderby CreatedTime descending
select new 
{
    IdChatUser = g.Key.IdChatUser, 
    Nama = g.Key.Nama, 
    Hp = g.Key.Hp, 
    CreatedTime = CreatedTime
}
```

Comment: Thank you,,, this work but the results are not ordered by CreatedTime descending

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `ChatUser` and `ChatUserConversation` `C#` entities, you could do this.

```
var results = ChatUser.Select(x=> new 
         {
             x.idchatuser,
             x.Name,
             x.Hp,
             CreatedTime =  ChatUserConversation .Where(c=> c.IdChatUser = x.IdChatUser)
                                                 .Max(c=>c.CreatedTime)  
         })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: i have tried this solution, but don't know how parsing the results to view.
i use asp.net mvc C#

Comment: You mean query is working, but don't know how to use it in view?

Comment: i don't know working or not because when i debug i get error in view